# spacy: set only one entity per type per sentence

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am new to `spacy` and found the docs rather complex for a beginner. My current project requires me to create a new model with custom entities, which I did following [this article](https://sematext.com/blog/entity-extraction-with-spacy/#:%7E:text=our%20own%20model.-,Training%20a%20new%20model,PERSON%20%C2%A0%7C%20%C2%A0Rafa%C5%82%20Ku%C4%87%0ATECH%20%C2%A0%7C%20%C2%A0High,-Conclusions%20and%20next).

Now, the sentences I'm workin with only have one or none entities per type per sentence.
**Dummy example:** *John* (`PERSON`) *is American* (`NATIONALITY`)*.* Only one `PERSON` tag and only one `NATIONALITY` tag in the sentence.

The problem I have is that when I pass new sentences to the model, sometimes it identifies more than one `PERSON`, even though there is always one or none.
**Dummy example:** *John* (`PERSON`) *went to McDonald's* (`PERSON`)*.*

**My question is:** is there any way to make the model to only identify one entity per type in each sentence?
(In the last example I suppose the model would know then that *John* fits better than *McDonald's* and choose *John* as the only `PERSON`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. Knowing in advance that there's only one of a particular entity per sentence isn't typical so NER isn't usually designed with that in mind.

You could use the spancat model instead to get scores and pick the highest scoring entity of each type, but you'd have to train it from scratch. Also your problems seems close enough to traditional NER that the assumptions the NER makes should help your accuracy normally.

Comment: I will do some research on spancat and see if I'm able to solve the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you are looking for is supported out-of-the-box by spaCy. You will have to implement something on top of what spaCy gives you in order to keep only entities of one type per sentence. How you would do that is also not clear given that there are no scores assigned to entity predictions by the Transition Based Parser NER for you to rank these predictions to choose the best one.

Depending on your use-case if these are short sentences and you only want the one entity per type, then choosing the first one might be good enough?

Comment: I think choosing the first entity per type could be good enough for now, although it is not very rigorous. Thank you very much for the information!